# multiplying PWM signal

Tags: mosfet, pwm, gate-driving

I have a 36 mosfets to drive them with a microcontroller (of course not all at the same time) and a gate drivers but i'm trying to figure out a way on which i minimaze the number of gate drivers as 36 one will be very costly.

So can i from one gate driver output multiply that PWM signal to the others mosfets ?  like using a demultipexer( even that using a demultiplexer will devider my frequency and then i will loose my signal)

[image]

Is there any solution to drive many mosfets with a single PWM signal without losing the frequency of the signal ?

Comment: Post a schematic! Start sentences with capital letter. I is capital letter.

Comment: An example schematic with waveforms would do wonders. But if those 32 MOSFETs need to work, each, then all of them will have to be driven, somehow.

Comment: There are very low resistance multiplexers but I'm not sure they would be easier or cheaper than just using 36 drivers and multiplexing the input signals. This seems like the kind of design trade-off that you really have to work through to the end with several alternatives and weight the options, taking into account technical and non-technical factors.

Comment: To make sure we're not dealing with a XY problem, what are these 36 MOSFETs being used for?

Comment: they are used for cell balancing system for 36 cells of a battery pack

Comment: Assuming the balancing current is small, you can probably get by without any gate driver. Just use a current limiting resistor into the gate, and keep the pwm frequency low.

Comment: If you want to drive all of them with exactly same signal you don't need anything, except maybe a buffer or two to keep up with the load. However this is not how I would expect balancing circuit to work. Shouldn't each mosfet be controlled individually?